# Chart.js and loading parameters from Hiddenfields

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I've got Chart.js bar graph working on a page where the chart works if the information is statically set. What i would like to do though is remove the statically set values and replace with information constructed through code-behind and loaded into a Hiddenfield.

This is my Hiddenfield holding a value that was set from code-behind.

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="HFType" runat="server" Value="'Sold', 'Inventory'" />
```

This is my Canvas tag.

```
<canvas id="inv-sales" style="display: block; width: 100%;" class="chartjs-render-monitor"></canvas>
```

Here is the Script

```
<script>
    var myChart = document.getElementById("inv-sales").getContext("2d");

    var myChartData = {
        labels: ['Sold', 'Inventory'],
        datasets: [{
            data: [200, 100],
            backgroundColor: ['#333333', '#333333'],
            hoverBackgroundColor: ['#000000', '#000000']
        }]
    };

    var myChart = new Chart(myChart, {
        type: 'horizontalBar',
        data: myChartData,
        options: {
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        min: 60
                    }
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    stacked: true
                }]
            }

        }
    });
</script>
```

All of that works fine. What i would now like to do is replace the Labels and dataset data with dynamically created data.

I have an asp.net hiddenfield which is HFType and it's value is 'Sales','Inventory'
If within the script, i try this;

```
var xHFType = document.getElementById('<% =HFType.ClientID %>').value;
labels: [xHFType],
```

or this;

```
var xHFType = document.getElementById('<% =HFType.ClientID %>').value;
labels: xHFTypee,
```

Neither work. If i ensured that I had 2 parameters for the data, background color and hover color also, it just combines the 'sales','inventory' into one label and does not split them.

Any ideas what I can do to load this 'array' of data in?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to update the data in your chart dynamically when the "HFType" value changes. I don't know your HTML structure, but the basic idea is to add an event to your hidden field, so when it changes, would call a function that then updates the chart.

Something like this:

`<input name="my_hidden_field" onchange=updateChart()>`

And a function:

```
function updateChart(event){
    myChart.data.labels = event.target.value;
    myChart.update();
}
```

Please note this is just a guide of the idea, since I don't know much more details about your HTML and JavaScript.

More information here:

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html

Comment: HI Bruno, thanks for your comment and whilst this isn't exactly what i'm after, I do like this and so have saved this snippet of functionality. The problem i'm trying to solve is how do i use my Hiddenfield data within the jQuery?

Comment: Hi @Stephen85, I am not sure I understand your question. What do you mean by "how do i use my Hiddenfield data within the jQuery?"